# in java I need define date in this format 1999-05-31T13:20:00-05:00

Tags: java, date

I need to define date in this format `1999-05-31T13:20:00-05:00`

I am using below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

String date = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
```

but it is generating date in format `2017-04-117T08:28:46-0500` (missing semicolon in timezone)

After defining the date I have to create an instance of XMLGregorianCalendar with same date.

Comment: There are a lot of samples in the internet

Comment: What have you tried, and what you having trouble with?

Comment: Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) One of its examples looks like your expected result.

Comment: If you can, use the `java.time` classes. The format you are asking for is exactly what [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) is giving you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was surprised you didn’t find the answer when searching for it. Anyway, it’s easy. Two words of caution first, though:

- Skip the three-letter time zone abbreviations. Many are ambiguous. While I think EST only means Eastern Standard Time, this isn’t a full time zone, since (most of?) that zone is on EDT now, which does not make it very clear what result you want.
- If there’s any way you can, skip the old-fashioned classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. The new classes in `java.time` are generally much nicer to work with.

The format you are asking for is exactly what [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) is giving you. If you meant to have the time formatted suitably for a user in the Eastern time zone, use:

```
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

Note the use of the unambiguous time zone ID and of the mentioned formatter. The format will print milliseconds (and even smaller) if there are any, which you didn’t ask for. So I have cheated a bit: I am truncating the time to whole seconds. Now this prints something like:

```
2017-04-27T10:11:33-04:00
```

If instead you wanted the offset `-05:00`, that’s even easier:

```
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5))
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(now);
```

This prints something in the same format, but with the desired offset:

```
2017-04-27T09:11:33-05:00
```

The `toString` method of `OffsetDateTime` gives you the format you want. Of course, if you prefer, you can use the same formatter as before.

If truncating to seconds is a bit too much cheating for your taste, you may of course use a formatter without milliseconds:

```
    DateTimeFormatter isoNoSeconds = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    System.out.println(now.format(isoNoSeconds));
```

This will work with both a `ZonedDateTime` and an `OffsetDateTime`, that is, with both of the above snippets.

Comment: nice! didn't know about the `truncatedTo()` effect. So the final form would be similar to `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("EST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)`

Comment: Yes. That too gives the `-05:00` offset in the formatted date-time since `SHORT_IDS` translate EST to -05:00 (not to America/New_York or any other specific location). The translations don’t seem to follow a clear pattern.

Comment: yes indeed, SHORT_IDS define mappings between short ids and the corresponding IDs described in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). EST, HST, MST are fixed compared with the others which map to a specific region. So the result will be that `ZoneId.of("EST", map)` will have no `ZoneRules`, while `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` will have `ZoneRules`. So better to stick with `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` as we'll get daylight saving time for that zone.